# How to combine hash in PHP

Tags: php, hash, hashcode

I would like to ask if how to combine hash codes in PHP?

For example I have some checksums here (just sample checksums):

```
checksum1:b62e146dbc34b6f7dd0d7b1dc4e6c93ebc2a0016793e3af701fe4f3eab3299d1
checksum2:dsfhsdf8s6f87e4r34ijtr5i34u5934534534ij5340598348534095834095j34
checksum3:4324298sdfhsdhfsdhf387455hsdfhsdf9358903485jsdfjsdjfsiuf03458345
```

If I have these sample checksums of a file which will be split into 3 parts, I have to combine the first 2 checksums and then combine the last checksum after.

Edit: Combine means if I combine 2 checksums, it will generate new checksum.

I would like to achieve through the code what was stated in here:

> Combine the first two hashes and take the binary hash of the result.
>
> $ cat hash1 hash2 > hash12
>
> $ openssl dgst -sha256 -binary hash12 > hash12hash

This is in the command line interface. The binary result was later on converted to hexadecimal.
How is it possible for PHP?

Comment: Define what you mean by "combine".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I mean combine hashcodes like if I combine the first 2 checksums, it will generate new checksum. I'll update my question

Comment: Why output binary?

Comment: Your example checksums are alphanumeric, but your openssl example outputs binary.  It doesn't seem like you know what output your teacher wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use . operator to combine

```
        $checksum1='b62e146dbc34b6f7dd0d7b1dc4e6c93ebc2a0016793e3af701fe4f3eab3299d1';
        $checksum2='dsfhsdf8s6f87e4r34ijtr5i34u5934534534ij5340598348534095834095j34';
        $checksum3='4324298sdfhsdhfsdhf387455hsdfhsdf9358903485jsdfjsdjfsiuf03458345';

echo $checksum1.$checksum2.$checksum3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function, for example as in the following body-less for-loop:

```
$checksums = [ 
    'b62e146dbc34b6f7dd0d7b1dc4e6c93ebc2a0016793e3af701fe4f3eab3299d1',
    'dsfhsdf8s6f87e4r34ijtr5i34u5934534534ij5340598348534095834095j34',
    '4324298sdfhsdhfsdhf387455hsdfhsdf9358903485jsdfjsdjfsiuf03458345'
];


for ($i = 1, $hash = $checksums[0];
     $i < sizeof($checksums);
     $i++, $hash = hash('sha256', $hash.$checksums[$i]));

echo $hash;
```

This will calculate the hash as `hash(hash(checksum1 + checksum2) + checksum3)`

In your question, you use the `-binary` flag with the `openssl dgst` command. You can do the same in PHP by passing a `true` value as the third parameter in the call to the PHP `hash()` function, but I don't really see how that is meaningful if you start combining more than two hashes.

**Update**

In the comments, it was made clear that the actual goal is to calculate a tree hash for use with AWS. The easiest way to to that is to use the [`TreeHash`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Glacier.TreeHash.html) class from the AWS SDK for PHP.

Comment: I tried your method but the final checksum still mismatched with how the Amazon glacier calculate the checksum of my file. Initially, I provided the checksum of the entire file without splitting it using the hash_file function but the result of the request states that the checksum I provided is different from them. They have steps here [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html] to calculate the checksum but I'm having difficulty to put it into code. That's why I tried splitting the parts, combine the checksum, but it's still mismatched checksums.

Comment: Um... that was information that would not have been out of place in your original question. Do you have the expected output value?

Comment: Rob, yes, the checksum of my file is this: `5fa66f717951b770ffefc9ee9db5fa431bba5ed3135ec626d3e52044011eb9a6` and the computed value from them is this `ca20a6f0cea34fa23ef4cd04f782554b279f30a754ecba46ca5b65842dfdc785`. I just use the `hash_file` function to get the checksum of the file. I really don't know if what is wrong with the checksums.

Comment: And this value is the value corresponding to the three checksums that you provided, right? I mean, it's the same file we're talking about?

Comment: No Rob,I'm sorry, It's just sample checksums. I just want to know if how those checksums will be combined. Just the algorithm of the code. But the one I provided to you recently is the right checksum of the file without splitting it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but we're using the new version of their api. [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Glacier.TreeHash.html#_addChecksum] . This is different from the old version. Can I ask you some few things on chat if it's okay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139320/discussion-between-robby-cornelissen-and-g-curs).

Answer (score 1):

I had already found the answer to my question. I used [Tree hash](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Glacier.TreeHash.html#_addChecksum) class in the AWS SDK and add the checksums using the `addChecksum` function and pass the checksum of each splitted file so as to make the 2 checksums matched.
Thank you for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would implode and then explode it.  It's great for storing hashes in files and etc:

```
<?php

$checkSums = Array(
    "b62e146dbc34b6f7dd0d7b1dc4e6c93ebc2a0016793e3af701fe4f3eab3299d1",
    "dsfhsdf8s6f87e4r34ijtr5i34u5934534534ij5340598348534095834095j34",
    "4324298sdfhsdhfsdhf387455hsdfhsdf9358903485jsdfjsdjfsiuf03458345"
);
//simply combine via $checksum1 . '|' . $checksum2 . '|' . $checksum3, and then explode it the way listed bellow

$combined = implode('|', $checkSums);

$notCombined = explode('|', $combined);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke `openssl` with `system()` or `exec()`

```
<?php
$checksum = system( "openssl dgst -sha256 -binary hash12" );
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Jim U, I tried that by the system function is disabled in the project.

Comment: When asking a question, tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: If you need to generate an openssl solution using native php functions, see the [OpenSSL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php)